# Is it possible to add conditional for loop in nested ones?

Tags: java, for-loop

In an ordinary nested for-loop, is it possible to put a condition to determine whether to run a specific for loop in a nested loop?

For example, in a code like below, is it possible to skip second for-statement(int j) when int i of the first loop is < 3?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
            //hell a lot of codes
        }
    }
}
```

so that only when i < 3, the actual executed code looks like this?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for(int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
        //hell a lot of codes   
    }
}
```

The reason why I want to do this is that the inner-most codes are quite long as well as the number of the for loops (about 10 nested), and really don't want to repeat them again. I can think of doing this with methods, but I am not quite familiar with methods and OO programming.

Much appreciated,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, I'd probably extract the code to a separate method. But here's a workaround if you don't want to do that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < (i < 3 ? 1 : 3); j++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
            //hell a lot of codes
        }
    }
}
```

This way, if `i < 3`, the `j` loop will only execute once.

---

The method approach would roughly look something like this:

```
void outer() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if(i < 3) {
            inner(i, 0);
        } else {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                inner(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}

void inner(int i, int j) {
    for(int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
        //hell a lot of codes
    }
}
```

You may want to make the methods static, or private, or remove the parameter(s), or add a return type, etc. It's hard to say with just the code in your question.

Comment: It helps to read the question (and also to ask a good question).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi, is there something I did poorly in the question? I'll edit if needed :D

Comment: @shmosel Hi, thanks for the help. It'd be even greater if you could direct me to the method way. :)